# Changing display output on Nvidia graphics card(NVCPL.DLL)

Tags: c++, dll, graphics, nvidia

I am trying change my graphics card setting progmatically. I have nvidia 570 GTX graphics card connected to two computer monitors and one LCD TV. The problem is that my 570 GTX can only output two displays at one time so I am constantly switching between my monitors and my TV from within the control panel. I want to make a program that automates this process.
I am planning on using Nvidia's api to change the graphics cards settings:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/9.5/Samples/DEMOS/common/src/NvCpl/docs/NVControlPanel_API.pdf

The problem is I have no idea how to do this in C++; how to import and implement the dll calls, which function to use etc.

Does anyone wanna take a quick crack at it for me? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you plan to do this in c#, remove the c++ tag from the question